# Problema para obtener el nombre por teclado

Tags: java, clase

En ese código, solo obtiene la nota, pero no el nombre de la asignatura, no me de error de compilación.

¿Alguien sabe como corregirlo?

```
private void anadirAsignatura(){
        String nombre;
        double nota;
        Asignatura a=null;
        System.out.println("Escriba el nombre de la nueva asignatura: ");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Escriba la nota de la nueva asignatura: ");

        nota = teclado.nextDouble();

        a=new Asignatura(nombre, nota);

        if (alumno.nuevaAsignatura(a)){
            System.out.println("Asignatura aÒadida correctamente ");

        }
        else 
            System.out.println("No se ha podido aÒadir ");
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Capturar el nombre  con `teclado.next()` y luego un `teclado.nextLine();` para el enter. Posteriormente ya capturar la nota con `teclado.nextDouble()`

Comment: @Dev.Joel aunque en ocasiones yo también doy indicaciones por comentarios, el tuyo me parece más una respuesta completa y creo que deberías escribirla como tal.

Comment: @SJuan76 mejor usar la pregunta duplicada.